# Why isn't Pygments working in Pidgin on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, syntax-highlighting, pidgin, pygments

I'm trying to get code syntax highlighting working in [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/download/linux/). I've installed it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kip/pidgin
sudo apt-get install -y pidgin pidgin-sipe
```

It works fine and I'm able to chat with my team. I've also installed [Pygments](http://pygments.org/):

```
sudo pip3 install Pygments
```

However, no code highlighting works. For example, this simple test fails:

````
```test```
````

There's no plugin listed in Pidgin for Pygments, but I haven't been able to determine whether there should be. There are no other code-related plugins listed, either.

What else can I check for? Does Pygments somehow need to be installed in Pidgin itself?

Reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/pidgin/discussion/markdown_syntax#md_ex_code

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin doesn't support markdown for formatting. Instead, it uses a formatting toolbar that creates HTML.

The markdown_syntax page you link to is just a page about formatting a wiki page on SourceForge, not to do with the Pidgin application itself.

You'll want to look on the https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins page to see if there's any code-highlighting plugins for Pidgin, however I'm not aware of any that exist.